# Python: Creating clean code with lots of lists

Tags: python

In an attempt to become a better programmer I want to be able to create a cleaner code and one of the things that looks "messy" on the way I currently code is how I manage lists.

Typically I will (in the beginning of the code) start by defining the lists like this (below are completely arbitrary values I set into the lists) and then i iterate the proces many times throughout loops:

```
for i in range(100):
     value1 = []
     datapre = []
     datapost = [] 

     value1.append('Name')
     value1.append('Number')
     datapre.append(13)
     dapre.append(16)
     datapost.append(25)
     datapost.append(28)
```

The above example only has 3 lists, however some times I need to use many different lists (like 50), which makes the code quite long, and I expect that good programmers do not actually work like this. So can anyone provides some tips on how you actually should store data?

Comment: in python lists do not have to be initialised. You can just create them on the spot with list-comprehensions. However, if you want to append data, the data structure you are appending to has to exist. In short, *initialise and append* if you want to append, otherwise create on demand.

Comment: If your code is complete, you can post it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/and get feedback on how to improve it. For what it's worth, I do it your way too

Comment: @Mawg The question as it stands is not a good fit for code review. The code presented lacks context. Code Review deals with actual specific code from a real usage context, not with abstracted and minified examples. See the [CR help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and the [Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow Users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777)

Comment: Maybe you should start writing classes instead of storing everything in ever-growing lists. Without more context it's hard to say.

Comment: @Vogel612 That's why I was very careful to say "If your code is complete, you can post it  ...", meaning post all of the code, not just a fragment

Comment: I edited my example somewhat to specifiy that I am resetting the lists over and over through loops so the lists aren't ever growing. It just becomes an issue when you need to define like 40-50 lists (my post only contains 3 lists)

Answer (score 0):

The *initialize-append* way:

```
my_list = []

for i in range(10):
    my_list.append(i**2)
```

---

The list-comprehension way:

```
my_list = [i**2 for i in range(10)]
```

What you choose to use depends on many factors, the most important of which (imo) is *what else is done with it apart from populating the list.* If they have to used elsewhere too, a for loop is advised to avoid re-iterating.

Then again, lists might not be the best choice in terms of data-structure for your specific problem, but that is impossible to judge from the info you provide.